# Create Windows project type in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

I can not see Windows application project. Could anyone help me? What should I do?

[image]

Comment: Reinstall Visual Studio.

Comment: Check other framework versions? up right ?

Comment: - Slaks, Aren't There another way of Reinstall?

- Philippe Pare, I want to create new window project. Actually, It will be File > New > Projcet... > C# > window. But I can not see "Window" under C# now.

Comment: It appears as though the ProjectTemplatesCache has been cleared.  From the Visual Studio Command Prompt run as Admin, execute the following command `devenv /installvstemplates`.

Comment: Thank you, TnTinMn. It's worked.

Comment: Reset you settings using the **Import and Export Settings** wizard.
Changes will be made to the IDE after you apply **General Development Settings.**

Comment: @TnTinMn Can you convert your comment into answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears as though the ProjectTemplatesCache has been cleared.

From the Visual Studio Command Prompt run as Administrator, execute the following command:

```
devenv /installvstemplates
```

For more information, see:  [/InstallVSTemplates (devenv.exe)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms241279.aspx).